# Javascript wait on async forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, async-await

I am creating MongoDB records based on user inputs, and then for each new object created, I am pushing the object ID into an array. My problem is my console.log statement in the last line returns empty. So How I could wait on the forEach execution to be over so I have the updated assetsArray, any help is appreciated!
Here is my code:

```
let assetsArray = [];
if (assets) {
  JSON.parse(assets).forEach(asset => {
    Image.create({
      organization: organizationID,
      imageName: asset.imageName,
      imageDescription: asset.imageDescription ?? null,
      imagePath: asset.imagePath
    }).then(record => {
      console.log(record)
      assetsArray.push(record._id)
    })
  })
}
console.log(assetsArray)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)  for your case

```js
const tasks = JSON.parse(assets).map(asset => {
  return Image.create({
    organization: organizationID,
    imageName: asset.imageName,
    imageDescription: asset.imageDescription ?? null,
    imagePath: asset.imagePath,
  })
});

Promise.all(tasks).then((records) => {
  return records.map(record => {
    console.log(record)
    return record._id
  })
}).then(assetsArray => {
  console.log(assetsArray)
})
```

Comment: Let me update the code snippet

Comment: Updated @Jacky.S

Comment: Thanks @hackape for your contribution.

Comment: My new question is how would I able to use ```assetsArray``` outside the ```.then()``` function. For example, after that code block, I am creating a new MongoDB object, that needs the assetsArray to be filled first

Comment: Use can use await instead of .then

Comment: const records = await Promise.all(tasks);
const recordIds = records.map(record => record._id);